# How to call solidity function from javascript file? Keep getting error deploying through truffle and webpack

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, javascript

Error -> TypeError: fetch.amount is not a function
[WDS] Disconnected!

Please explain or provide code on how to call solidity function

Trying to call from ready() function

console.log(contract.abi)
This line gave me

```
(11) […]
0: Object { constant: true, name: "amount", payable: false, … }
(11) […]
​
0: Object { constant: true, name: "amount", payable: false, … }
​
1: Object { constant: true, name: "homeBet", payable: false, … }
​
2: Object { constant: true, name: "awayBet", payable: false, … }
​
3: Object { payable: false, stateMutability: "nonpayable", type: "constructor", … }
​
4: Object { payable: false, stateMutability: "nonpayable", type: "fallback" }
​
5: Object { anonymous: false, name: "LogInfo", type: "event", … }
​
6: Object { constant: false, name: "betOnTeam", payable: true, … }
​
7: Object { constant: false, name: "__callback", payable: false, … }
​
8: Object { constant: false, name: "__callback", payable: false, … }
​
```

​

App.js

````````````````````
// Import the page's CSS. Webpack will know what to do with it, 
// as it's been configured by truffle-webpack
import "../stylesheets/app.css";

// Import libraries we need.
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'
// Import our contract artifacts and turn them into usable abstractions.
// Make sure you've ran truffle compile first
import contract_build_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/OraclizeTest.json'

// OraclizeContract is our usable abstraction, which we'll use through the code below.
var OraclizeContract = contract(contract_build_artifacts);

var accounts;
var account;

document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      ready();
    }
  }

window.App = {

  // 'Constructor'
  start: function() {


    // Bootstrap the Contract abstraction for use with the current web3 instance
    OraclizeContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

    // Get the initial account balance so it can be displayed.
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
      if (err != null) {
        alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
        return;
      }

      if (accs.length == 0) {
        alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
        return;
      }

      accounts = accs;
      account = accounts[0];


    });
  },

  // Show an error
  setStatus: function(message) {
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = message;
  },



}
// Front-end entry point

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    console.warn("Using web3 detected from external source. If you find that your accounts don't appear or you have 0 MetaCoin, ensure you've configured that source properly. If using MetaMask, see the following link. Feel free to delete this warning. :) http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask")
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://127.0.0.1:9545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask");
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:9545"));
  }

  // All systems go, start App!
  App.start();
});

function ready(){
document.getElementById("bet").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var fromAddress1 = document.querySelector("#bet #fromAddress1").value;
    var privateKey1 = document.querySelector("#bet #privateKey1").value;
    var fromAddress2 = document.querySelector("#bet #fromAddress2").value;
    var privateKey2 = document.querySelector("#bet #privateKey2").value;

    var betAmount = document.querySelector("#bet #betAmount").value;
    var contract = web3.eth.contract(OraclizeContract.abi);
    var fetch = contract.abi
    console.log(fetch.amount())
    console.log(contract.abi)
    var sendata = contact.new.getData(web3.toWei(betAmount, "ether"));

    var team = document.querySelector("#bet #team").value;

    if(team == "Home")
    {
      team = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      team = 2;
    }

    var amount = contract.amount();
    var data = contract.betOnTeam.getData(team);

  })
}
```````````````````
````````````````````

Comment: you're calling the method `amount` on `fetch` which you defined as `contract.abi`.  I expect you actually want `contract.amount()`

Comment: also it looks like you're using an old version of `web3` which i'm not familiar with, so I can't be certain, but be careful about how you're calling the methods on your contract object.  Check the docs on your web3 version.